# Web.config fails on staging environment, but runs locally?

Tags: asp.net

I'm running a staging environment on a dedicated ASP .NET server that has worked just fine until recently, where I added the following to the web.config file:

```
<location path="dashboard/api/ManageProjects.asmx">
<system.web>
  <webServices>
    <protocols>
      <add name="HttpGet"/>
    </protocols>
  </webServices>
</system.web>
</location>
<location path="administration/api/ManageProjects.asmx">
<system.web>
  <webServices>
    <protocols>
      <add name="HttpGet"/>
    </protocols>
  </webServices>
</system.web>
</location>
```

I honestly have no idea of why this would ruin the staging environment at all, but it gives me an error 500.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue by removing the location-content from the web.config file and then added the following, under the web.config's  section:

```
<webServices>
  <protocols>
    <clear />
    <add name="HttpGet"/>
    <add name="HttpPost"/>
  </protocols>
</webServices>
```